# In Bash, how do I interpolate $(...) in a string?

Tags: bash, shell, string-interpolation

I am attempting to write a Bash script that performs a mysqldump on my live site's database, then adds and commits the dump to a Git repository.  Here is what I have so far (stored in a .sh file which is called by a [crontab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#Overview) entry):

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump --skip-comments --skip-dump-date -u [user] -p[pass] database | gzip > /var/www/site/backup/database.sql.gz
cd var/www/site/backup && git add *
cd var/www/site/backup && git commit -m 'Database $(date +%a %H:%M %h %d %Y)'
```

My crontab entry looks like this:

```
0,20,40 8-22 * * * /var/www/site/backup/script.sh
```

I can see that this script does dump the database, but does not add or commit the file to Git. Is there something that I am missing?

---

Later I made the following changes and the commit works:

```
cd /var/www/site/backup && /usr/bin/git add *
cd /var/www/site/backup && /usr/bin/git commit -m 'Database $(date +%a %H:%M %h %d %Y)'
```

However, the date does not get calculated.

---

Latest revisions, including (most of) the recommendations:

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump --skip-comments --skip-dump-date -u [user] -p[pass] database > /var/www/site/backup/database.sql
cd var/www/site/backup
/usr/bin/git add *
/usr/bin/git commit -m "Internal Forms Live Database Dump Stored $(date '+%a %H:%M %h %d %Y')"
```

Comment: did you already check the status of your git-repository with `git status`?

Comment: Yes, that is how I knew the commits were not happening

Comment: Compressing your dump before adding it makes it impossible for git to store only differential data, git will take care of compressing data wherever possible on its own. Either leave it uncompressed or use git-annex instead.

Comment: good point, I'll take out the gzip command

Comment: I concur what Elias said. Also be sure to add `--skip-comments --skip-dump-date` to the `mysqldump` command to make the work for Git's xdelta compressor even easier.

Comment: Two more hints: 1) There's no point in repeatedly doing `cd`: do it once, and then call `git` several times: each process started by the shell inherits the shell's current directory (changed by the `cd` command), and can't affect it. 2) Do not pass passwords on the command line -- this is insecure as everyone is able to snatch them from the process list.  Instead, put the credentials to a well-protected file and pass its name to `mysqldump` using its `--defaults-extra-file=/path/to/that/file` command-line option.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

`$(...)` and [other forms of substitutions are not interpolated in single-quoted strings](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_02_02).

So if you want your date calculated, do

```
git commit -m "Database $(date '+%a %M:%H %h %d %Y')"
```

that is, the whole message string is double-quoted to allow `$(...)` to be interpolated while the argument to `date` is in single quotes to make it a single argument (passed to `date`).

Comment: I changed the &a to %a