# Dynamically replace current time inside docker-compose command

Tags: docker, docker-compose

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  pgdump:
    image: postgres:alpine
    command: pg_dump -f "backup-`date -u -Iseconds`.pg_restore" $DATABASE_URL
```

This produces a file named

`` backup-`date -u -Iseconds`.pg_restore ``

instead of the desired

`backup-2021-04-14T16:42:54+00:00.pg_restore`.

I also tried:

```
command: pg_dump -f backup-`date -u -Iseconds`.pg_restore $DATABASE_URL

command: pg_dump -f "backup-${date -u -Iseconds}.pg_restore" $DATABASE_URL

command: pg_dump -f backup-${date -u -Iseconds}.pg_restore $DATABASE_URL
```

All of them yield different errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of April 2021 command substitution is not supported by docker-compose according to this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4081).

As a workaround in my use case, one could either use native `docker run` commands, where substitution works or use an `.env` file.

Comment: That's very interesting, thanks for sharing this find.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure but I think this workaround worked for me: `command: bash -c "redis-server --cluster-enabled yes --cluster-config-file nodes.node-2.\`date +'%s'\`.conf --appendonly no --save '' --loadmodule /usr/lib/redis/modules/redistimeseries.so"`.

Answer (score 2):

### Current command

The date command itself is incorrect. Try running it on its own

```
date -u -Iseconds
echo `date -u -Iseconds`
```

From your command, I presume you want date in UTC seconds since epoch? Epoch by itself is UTC. So you just need seconds since Epoch. No need for `-u` parameter.

### Solution

Here's the correct command in two forms:

A.

```
    command: pg_dump -f "backup-`date +'%s'`.pg_restore" $DATABASE_URL
```

B.

```
    command: pg_dump -f "backup-$(date +'%s').pg_restore" $DATABASE_URL
```

### Explanation

There are multiple things to watch out for in the command you provided:

1. Notice the double quotes around the file name? This means you cannot nest another double-quote within the original outer pair without escaping the inner ones with `\`. Another alternative option is to use as many single-quote pairs you want within a pair of double-quotes. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23656236/10830091) and this [excerpt](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_02_02) about `2.2.2 Single-Quotes` and `2.2.3 Double-Quotes`.
2. For string interpolation, you can use either `$()` or ``` `` ``` notation. But NOT within single-quotes as I said.
3. As a dry-run test, create a file directly with said notations:

```
vi "backup-`date +'%s'`.txt"
vi "backup-$(date +'%s').txt"
```

4. As for date format. Both `GNU/date` `BSD/date` accept `%s` to represent seconds since Epoch. Find "%s" in [ss64](https://ss64.com/bash/date.html) or [man7](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html) or [cyberciti](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-formatting-dates-for-display/).
5. Docker-related, watch out what command does. [Source](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#command):

> `command` overrides the the default command declared by the container image (i.e. by Dockerfile's CMD).

Comment: Thanks for you elaborate answer! However, on my system (Debian) ``touch "backup-`date -u -Iseconds`.pg_restore"`` produces a correctly named file, while the same touch in a docker-compose.yml doesn’t. It literally prints the sub-command into the file name. So the real problem seems to be the sub-command not being executed.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the filename and store it as a variable with shell command before doing the pg_dump:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  pgdump:
    image: postgres:alpine
    entrypoint: ["/bin/sh","-c"]
    command: >
      "FILENAME=backup-`date -u -Iseconds`.pg_restore
      && pg_dump -f $$FILENAME $$DATABASE_URL"
```

Successfully tested against Docker image for postgres 13.6.